# Is it possible to web scrape an infinitely scrolling website using Python, without using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape information from a website. I am able to scrape the initial page the loads just fine, however it only loads 24 items at a time. You must continuously scroll down to the bottom of the page to force it to load the next 24 items. The only solutions I found online require Selenium.

```
html_path = 'https://www.nike.com/w/mens-shoes-nik1zy7ok'
raw_html = simple_get(html_path)
html = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')

'''
for div in html.select('div'):
    if div['class'] == 'product-card__title':
        print(div.text)
        '''
shoes = html.find_all("div", {"class" : "product-card__title"})
for i in shoes:
    print(i.text)
```

Comment: of course it is possible, it is actually faster than selenium.find the API request which gets the products information and make that request in scrapy

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the request directly which is made in the background when scrolling down. You will find it when you inspect the source-code of the website (ctrl + u) or make use of the DevTools of your browser (ctrl + shift + c) and check the Network-tab or the Console-tab. See what happens once you scroll down. You should notice that there are requests made to their API, which you can use and manipulate to get the data you are looking for.

Here is an example call if I'm interested in men's shoes that are on sale in Germany ("DE"):
https://www.nike.com/product_feed/rollup_threads/v2?filter=marketplace(DE)&filter=language(de)&filter=employeePrice(true)&filter=attributeIds(0f64ecc7-d624-4e91-b171-b83a03dd8550%2C16633190-45e5-4830-a068-232ac7aea82c%2C5b21a62a-0503-400c-8336-3ccfbff2a684)&anchor=0&consumerChannelId=d9a5bc42-4b9c-4976-858a-f159cf99c647&count=24

Change the `anchor`-value to set the start-item. In my example I want to start from the top, so I set it to 0.
Change the `count`-value to set the amount of items that are included in the response.

The response will be in json-format. If you want to extract the name of the shoe, the full price and the discounted current price of all the shoes in the response for example you could do the following:

```py
import scrapy
import json


class NikeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "nike"
    start_urls = ['https://www.nike.com/product_feed/rollup_threads/v2?filter=marketplace(DE)&filter=language(de)&filter=employeePrice(true)&filter=attributeIds(0f64ecc7-d624-4e91-b171-b83a03dd8550%2C16633190-45e5-4830-a068-232ac7aea82c%2C5b21a62a-0503-400c-8336-3ccfbff2a684)&anchor=0&consumerChannelId=d9a5bc42-4b9c-4976-858a-f159cf99c647&count=24']

    def parse(self, response):
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())

        for shoe in jsonresponse['objects']:
            yield {
                'Shoe Title': shoe['publishedContent']['properties']['title'],
                'Full Price': shoe['productInfo'][0]['merchPrice']['fullPrice'],
                'Discounted Price': shoe['productInfo'][0]['merchPrice']['currentPrice']
            }
```

Comment: I am unfamiliar with JSON formatting. How am I able to print the information gathered from the parse function?

Comment: If you don't want to yield the data but print it simply change the for loop to  `for shoe in jsonresponse['objects']:
            print(shoe['publishedContent']['properties']['title'])
            print(shoe['productInfo'][0]['merchPrice']['fullPrice'])
            print(shoe['productInfo'][0]['merchPrice']['currentPrice'])`

Comment: I think I am doing something wrong. I made a new file (nike_spider.py) and used the code you wrote above for the class. Then I created a Spider object and tried to call the parse function. I am getting an error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'body_as_unicode' "

Comment: It sounds like you should make yourself familiar with Scrapy first. Have a look at this [tutorial from the official scrapy documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html). It should all make sense then. Create a Scrapy project, set up your spider and then run it via `scrapy crawl nike`.